# Find the upper left position of a canvas

Tags: c#, canvas, unity-game-engine, position

To get the position of an object:

```
Vector3 mainCanvasPosition = mainCanvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position;
```

But it returns the position of the **center** of the object.

How can I get the upper left corner position?
[image]

Comment: You mean upper left position of the screen or just the canvas?

Comment: @Programmer Just the canvas (that holds the green panel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mainCanvas.GetComponent().rect.xMin gives you minimum x position of canvas in canvas space, not in world space. So if you add xMin to x position of canvas, you get minimum x position of canvas in world space. And same for y.

So;

```
var canvasTransform = mainCanvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
float minX = canvasTransform.position.x + canvasTransform.rect.xMin;
float maxY = canvasTransform.position.y + canvasTransform.rect.yMax;
float z = canvasTransform.position.z;

Vector3 topLeft = new Vector3(minX, maxY, z);
```

will give you top left of canvas

Edit: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-rect.html

If you look at Unity's reference, you should see that RectTransform.rect is in local space, not in world space

Comment: I had a problem with my internet and could not reply. As for my solution, you convert the local to world space with `TransformPoint` so that's not a problem at-all. Actually, I was testing mine through the scene view so I didn't notice that.

Comment: Anyone knows how to do it in javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

You should get the top left corner like this:

```
Vector3[] worldCorners = new Vector3[4];
mainCanvas.GetComponent<RectTransform().GetWorldCorners(worldCorners);
Vector3 topLeft = worldCorners[1];
```

In case you need this position to place something within your canvas you might consider to use local coordinates (transform.localPosition) with the top left corner set as anchor: